# Screen Blinking/Flickering in Application in Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Android 3.1 Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have this browser launching application which didn't have any problem till now: when it is being tested on Samsung Galaxy 10.1 (Model Number: GT-P7510) with Android 3.1 Honeycomb.

The issue is this: whenever I tap on a text box, the whole screen will flash across a black screen for a moment and revert back to normal. It starts flickering/blinking the black screen when I leave a focus on any text box as well.

Currently, I've no idea what is causing this issue as I've tested this application on several devices e.g. Samsung Galaxy S, Samsung Galaxy Tab 7-inch with previous version of OS from 2.1 to 2.3.

Anyone who has any clue as to what is going on whether be it a compatibility issue with the app or a change in function in honeycomb 3.1 or the device itself, please share your information and enlighten me on this matter please. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that this is not a solution, but I think I can shed some light on the problem.

We have recently been testing a functional jQuery Mobile HTML5 app wrapped with PhoneGap Android 2.x phones to the Galaxy tab 10.1. We have seen something very similar, with the exception that we have defined a splash screen for our app. What we see is that when an input field is given focus, the screen flashes up the splash screen momentarily. Very annoying! To verify if this is the same problem, define a splash screen for your PhoneGap app and see if the screen flahes your image instead of a black background. Knowing something about what's going on with PhoneGap and the Android WebView, this is my best estimation of what is happening: PhoneGap loads the main App activity with a black background and displays the splash screen (if defined) in that initial window. PhoneGap then starts the WebView and opens it on top of the main Window. When a field is selected, the Android invalidates the component wach time it updates it based on a focus event or keypress, or whatever, and Android redraws everything. So it redraws the main window behind the WebView and then redraws the WebView with the HTML page content on top of it. Since the device is not properly double-buffered, you see all of this redrawing in all its ugly glory right in front of your eyes.

We have seen serious glitches with Android web forms on some Android 2.x phones we have tested, and this looks like yet another glitch, but this time on the Galaxy Tab running Honeycomb (3.0).

We have attempted to use CSS -webkit-backface-visibility to resolve issues on some phones when experiencing flicker in the past - but this has caused serious rendering issues in HTML forms. Be warned! In theory this should be a viable fix to introduce some double-buffering into the mix, but in our experience it causes more problems than it solves.

I am not confident that this can be resolved, except by an Android software update from Google/Samsung.